# Sort HashMap keys based on the key size

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, hashmap

I have a `HashMap` in which keys are **Strings**. I need to take the keys and sort it based on the key size i.e. String length and then store it in some `ArrayList`.

**Note:** If two keys size is same, then we can place it in any order.

For eg.

```
hm.put("abc","hi");
hm.put("A","hi");
hm.put("ab","hi");
hm.put("a","hi");
```

My ArrayList should have elements in order `abc,ab,a,A`.

Can someone let me know what's the best possible way to do it.

Comment: You cannot sort a `HashMap` in place; create a `TreeMap` with a custom `Comparator` and add all your `HashMap` entries in it.

Comment: See `Comparator` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html think how you can implement it and use it in `sort(keys, yourComparator);`

Comment: By key size do you mean string length?

Comment: @Duncan - yes  Duncan

Answer (score 5):

You can sort the keys by length using a custom [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) like this:

```
List<String> s = new ArrayList<>(hm.keySet());
Collections.sort(s, new Comparator<String>(){
            @Override
            public int compare(String s1, String s2){
                 return Integer.compare(s2.length(), s1.length());
            }
});
```

---

Another possibility would be to use a [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) providing also here a custom [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to its constructor.

```
TreeSet<String> ts = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<String>(){
                     @Override
                     public int compare(String s1, String s2){
                           int cmp = Integer.compare(s2.length(), s1.length());
                           return cmp != 0 ? cmp : s1.compareTo(s2);
                     }
});
ts.addAll(hm.keySet());
```

Just note here that if the length of the pair of `Strings` you compare is the same, you have to compare also their lexicographical order, otherwise the `TreeSet` would just contains the `Strings` that have different length (i.e either "a" or "A" wouldn't be added to the set)